# I want to loop through each new added list item

Tags: javascript, arrays

My new list items are getting the remove and completed button added to the FIRST new item only and not the subsequent added items. The remove button is added to the new list item multiple times after entering a new item.

I tried doing length-1 but that didn't help.

```
function addTask() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("myTasks");
  var inputTask = document.getElementById("enterTask");
  var li = document.createElement("li")
  li.id = "new";
  //li.setAttribute('id',inputTask.value);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputTask.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  console.log(li);
  var newList = document.getElementById("new");
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) {
    var removeButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    removeButton.innerHTML = "Remove ☒";
    removeButton.className = "byebye";
    myListofTasks[i].appendChild(removeButton);
    removeButton.onclick = deleteItem;
    return;
    //  Creates a completed button
    let completeBtn = document.createElement("button");
    completeBtn.innerHTML = "Completed ★";
    completeBtn.className = "complete";
    completeBtn.onclick = strikeThrough;
    myListofTasks[i].appendChild(completeBtn);
  }
}

//Creates a remove button
const myListofTasks = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myListofTasks.length; i++) {
  let removeButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  //var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  removeButton.innerHTML = "Remove ☒";
  // var removeTxt = document.createTextNode("Remove ☒");
  removeButton.className = "byebye";
  //span.appendChild(removeTxt);
  myListofTasks[i].appendChild(removeButton);
  removeButton.onclick = deleteItem;

  function deleteItem(e) {
    var li = e.target.parentElement;
    var ul = document.getElementById("myTasks");
    ul.removeChild(li);
  }

  //  Creates a completed button
  let completeBtn = document.createElement("button");
  completeBtn.innerHTML = "Completed ★";
  completeBtn.className = "complete";
  completeBtn.onclick = strikeThrough;
  myListofTasks[i].appendChild(completeBtn);
}

function strikeThrough(e) {
  var li = e.target.parentElement;
  var ul = document.getElementById("myTasks");
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  e.target.parentElement.style.setProperty("text-decoration", "line-through");
}
```

I want to add a new item and for that item to have the same functionality as the items that were already displayed.

Comment: I will do rethink and rewrite the code! Bit messy and hard to understand easily!

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to iterate over li list each time you add a new node

```js
function addTask() {
    var ul = document.getElementById("myTasks");
    var inputTask = document.getElementById("enterTask");

    var li = document.createElement("li")
    li.id = "new";
    //li.setAttribute('id',inputTask.value);
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputTask.value));
    var removeButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    removeButton.innerHTML = "Remove &#9746";
    removeButton.className = "byebye";
    removeButton.onclick = deleteItem;
    li.appendChild(removeButton);
    let completeBtn = document.createElement("button");
    completeBtn.innerHTML = "Completed &#9733";
    completeBtn.className = "complete";
    completeBtn.onclick = strikeThrough;
    li.appendChild(completeBtn);
    ul.appendChild(li);
}



//Creates a remove button
const myListofTasks = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myListofTasks.length; i++) {
    let removeButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    //var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
    removeButton.innerHTML = "Remove &#9746";
    // var removeTxt = document.createTextNode("Remove &#9746");
    removeButton.className = "byebye";
    //span.appendChild(removeTxt);
    myListofTasks[i].appendChild(removeButton);

    removeButton.onclick = deleteItem;


    function deleteItem(e) {
        var li = e.target.parentElement;
        var ul = document.getElementById("myTasks");
        ul.removeChild(li);

    }

    //  Creates a completed button
    let completeBtn = document.createElement("button");
    completeBtn.innerHTML = "Completed &#9733";
    completeBtn.className = "complete";
    completeBtn.onclick = strikeThrough;
    myListofTasks[i].appendChild(completeBtn);
}


function strikeThrough(e) {
    var li = e.target.parentElement;
    var ul = document.getElementById("myTasks");
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    e.target.parentElement.style.setProperty("text-decoration", "line-through");
}
```

```html
<ul id="myTasks"> 
   <li>Do Laundry</li>
   <li>Do Car</li>
   <li>Email Dad</li>
   <li>Confirm Appt</li>
</ul>
<div id="enterANewTask">
   <input type="text" id="enterTask" name="enterTask" placeholder="Enter a task" value="" /> <br />
   <input type="button" id="newTask" name="newTask" placeholder="Enter a task" value="Enter" onclick=addTask(); /> <br />
</div>
```